# unity salto de personaje muy alto

Tags: unity

Me he decidio hacer un pequeño juego 2d en unity antes del año nuevo, la cuestion es que cuando presiono saltar (upArrow) es como si fuera un cohete, sale volando y nunca mas le vuelvo a ver, pero, por que sucede esto?
Este es el codigo:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player_controller : MonoBehaviour {

    public float maxSpeed = 5f;
    public float speed = 2f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Animator anim;
    public bool grounded;
    public float jumPower = 6.5f;
    private bool jump;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        anim.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(rb2d.velocity.x));
        anim.SetBool("grounded", grounded);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            jump = true;
        }

    }

    private void FixedUpdate(){
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.right * speed * h);

        /*  if (rb2d.velocity.x > maxSpeed)
          {
              rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
          }
          if (rb2d.velocity.x < -maxSpeed)
          {
              rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
          }*/

        float limitedSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(rb2d.velocity.x, -maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(limitedSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);

        if (h > 0.1f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
        }

        if (h < -0.1f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, 1f, 1f);
        }

        if (jump)
        {
            rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        Debug.Log(rb2d.velocity.x);
    }
}
```

todo funciona bien a excepcion del salto, que en vez de saltar es como si fuera despegar.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fijate que en `update` cuando presionas `UpArrow` pone una variable en `true` y luego en fixedupdate le haces un add force impulso mientras `jump` sea `true` el cual es siempre `true` ya que no hay nada que lo pone en false, deberias ponerle el metodo `keypressed` creo que es, asi cuando sueltas la `w`  el impulso desaparece y haces:

```
if (Input.GetKeyPressed(KeyCode.UpArrow))
   jump = true;
else
   jump = false;
```

Si mal no recuerdo ese es un metodo existente

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya resolvi con tu sugerencia, la tenia simpre true xD. Muchas gracias otra vez